# Pass date from <input type="date> in html to flask in HTML with onchange option to Python

Tags: javascript

I'm kinda new to coding so this might be a stupid question but I do need your help.

Is there anyway to pass date value from (input type="date") with onchange option in HTML to Python with normal format from html like

'YYYY-MM-DD' ?.

My purpose is to use that date value to query data with sqlalchemy on Flask and Postgresql db.

I successfully did it with submit button. but now, I want to use onchange option instead.

Answer (score 0):

*I successfully did it with submit button. but now, I want to use onchange option instead.*

You can do it using bit of JavaScript. Create `<script>` tag and define function inside it, something like:

```
function sendForm(){
  document.getElementById("id_of_your_form").submit();
}
```

replacing `"id_of_your_form"` with real id of your `<form>`. In HTML element set `onchange="sendForm()"`.